if you have $mn + m+n$ variables and m+n equations involving, how do you know that you can omit an equation to solve for $m+n-1$ variables?
I'm reading this paper and I'm wondering how what I asked above is intuitively true, based on the equations shown below. Let the total product shipped from the $i^{th}$ factory to the $n$ cities be $f_i$; this means we have the equations
$\begin{array}{c}x_{11}+x_{12}+\cdots+x_{1n}=f_1\\
x_{21}+x_{22}+\cdots+x_{2n}=f_2\\ \vdots\\x_{m1}+x_{m2}+\cdots+x_{mn}=f_m\end{array}$ which we may be called the F-equations for convenience. Let also the total product be consumed by the $j^{th}$ city be $c_j$ tons; this means we have the equations$\begin{array}{c}x_{11}+x_{12}+\cdots+x_{1n}=c_1\\x_{21}+x_{22}+\cdots+x_{2n}=c_2\\ \vdots\\x_{m1}+x_{m2}+\cdots+x_{mn}=c_n\end{array}$.

In one of your two systems of equations, all the subscripts of $x$ are in the wrong order.

Please proof-read your title.  It makes no sense and some words seem to be missing.  Please put the question in the body of the post.  The title should not just be the first sentence of your question, but should be a short summary. The body of your question should be self-contained and should make sense even if we read it without reading the title.  Please state the question in the body of your post.  Thank you!

It seems to me you only have $mn$ variables, and $m+n$ equations.
Nonetheless, as far as the ability to omit one equation goes:
If you sum up all the $f_i$ equations, you'll notice that $f_1+...+f_m=c_1+...+c_n$, with some rearranging. Thus, for example, $f_1=c_1+...+c_n-f_2-...-f_m$, which means the information provided by $f_1$ is already "covered" in the rest of the equations. All in all, at least one of the $f_i$ (or $c_i$) is dependent on the others.
On a smaller scale just to be concrete, let's consider:
$f_1=x_{11}+x_{12}$,  $f_2=x_{21}+x_{22}$
$c_1=x_{11}+x_{21}$,  $c_2=x_{12}+x_{22}$
Then, $f_1+f_2={x_{11}}+x_{12}+x_{21}+x_{22}=(x_{11}+x_{21})+(x_{12}+x_{22})=c_1+c_2$,
and we see that: $f_1=c_1+c_2-f_2$
